# How to apply RANSAC on OpenSurf matching results in matlab?

Tags: matlab, surf, ransac

I'm working on image processing with matlab. I want to match 2D Features extacted from Opensurf [Code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf--including-image-warp-), and How can I apply RANSAC to remove the outliers on matlab code.